# HTML 5 SSE and Json - Json to array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, json

**Check update below, topic closed**

I am new in Server-sent events and not used Json in Javascript yet (only php).
I am trying to get data from each object, but it wont work.
A foreach loop would be fine too

This is my script to read my Json:

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("json.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var b = event.data.replace(/'/g, '"');
        var obj = JSON.parse(b);
        console.log(obj.AUDCAD.Bid);
    };

} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}

</script>
```

My output recieved in the Javascript (**event.data**):

```
{ 'AUDCAD':[{'Bid':'0.92599', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'+0.23%'}]}
{ 'AUDJPY':[{'Bid':'85.24575', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'-0.66%'}]}
{ 'AUDNZD':[{'Bid':'1.090025', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'+0.24%'}]}
{ 'AUDUSD':[{'Bid':'0.7078', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'-0.32%'}]}
{ 'CADJPY':[{'Bid':'91.97097', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'-0.82%'}]}
{ 'EURAUD':[{'Bid':'1.5778', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'+0.82%'}]}
{ 'EURCAD':[{'Bid':'1.4633', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'+0.89%'}]}
{ 'EURCHF':[{'Bid':'1.09118', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'-0.07%'}]}
{ 'EURCZK':[{'Bid':'27.0235', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'+0.58%'}]}
{ 'EURGBP':[{'Bid':'0.738611', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'+0.04%'}]}
{ 'EURJPY':[{'Bid':'134.6803', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'-0.01%'}]}
{ 'EURUSD':[{'Bid':'1.1185', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'+0.34%'}]}
{ 'GBPJPY':[{'Bid':'182.2945', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'+0.01%'}]}
{ 'GBPUSD':[{'Bid':'1.5142', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'+0.34%'}]}
{ 'NZDUSD':[{'Bid':'0.6488', 'Color':'#9F0226', 'Proc':'-0.65%'}]}
{ 'USDCAD':[{'Bid':'1.3084', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'+0.54%'}]}
{ 'USDCHF':[{'Bid':'0.9754', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'-0.39%'}]}
{ 'USDJPY':[{'Bid':'120.39', 'Color':'#00652B', 'Proc':'-0.33%'}]}
```

I replaced single qoutes with double qoutes on line 5, because of errors.

I am not sure if i created my Json in the right way, i just read out an xml file in php and made a Json for it.

```
      <?php //here runs a loop
        { 
echo"data: { '".$v->Symbol."':[{'Bid':'".$v->Bid."', 'Color':'".$cc."', 'Proc':'".$sign.$p."'}]}\n\n"; }
     echo "retry: 10000\n\n"; ?>
```

i hope somebody can help me, anyway thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
I am now using this and thats all i needed

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("json.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var b = event.data.replace(/'/g, '"');
        var obj = JSON.parse(b);        
    for(var key in obj){
        console.log(key+' Bid:'+obj[key].Bid+' Color:'+obj[key].Color+' Proc:'+obj[key].Proc);
    }    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
echo"data: { '".$v->Symbol."':{'Bid':'".$v->Bid."', 'Color':'".$cc."', 'Proc':'".$sign.$p."'}}\n\n";
```

Comment: `AUDCAD` is an array, try `console.log(obj.AUDCAD[0].Bid);`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but then i get his: Uncaught TypeError: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Try to just `console.log(obj)` first, your data has a different property (AUDCAD, EURCHF...) everytime. You can traverse an object like this `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { console.log(obj[key] });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    tmp = obj[key][0];
    Object.keys(tmp).forEach(function(k) {
        console.log(k + ':' + tmp[k]);
    }); 
});
```

You'll traverse any format of data you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Hello your "AUDCAD" object is Array and inside the array you have added the object so you need will get that by using

```
obj['AUDCAD'][0]['Bid'];
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but after the console log i get an additional error: `0.92599
17(index):15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Please check JSON there is one Object have not Bid , Color... Values

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> { 'AUDCAD':[{'Bid':
> ```

That is not JSON and will cause `JSON.parse` to error. Strings in JSON must be delimited with `"`. `'` is not acceptable. See also http://jsonlint.com/

> I replaced single qoutes with double qoutes on line 5, because of errors

Fix the problem at the source. Don't hack it at the last second. You'll run in to problems with your data contains `'` or `"` as real data.

> I am not sure if i created my Json in the right way

Don't generate JSON by mashing strings together. You will make a mistake.

Generate a proper PHP data structure using arrays etc. Then pass it through [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

> ```
> obj.AUDCAD.Bid
> ```

`AUDCAD` is an array of objects, not a single object.

You need something more along the lines of `obj.AUDCAD[0].Bid`

Comment: The problem was that Sever-send events doesnt allow me to send double qoutes, some how no data gets send with double qoutes

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access your data with `obj.AUDCAD.Bid` change the php code to

```
echo"data: { '".$v->Symbol."':{'Bid':'".$v->Bid."', 'Color':'".$cc."', 'Proc':'".$sign.$p."'}}\n\n"; }
```

(without the [ ]), otherwise you have to access it with `obj.AUDCAD[0].Bid` because `obj.AUDCAD` is a array with 1 Object inside.

Now to access all the data try a for loop like this:

```
for(var key in obj)
    console.log(obj[key].Bid)
```

Comment: Even cleaner then my last update, works like a charm